# Using LDAP for authentication messes up my PowerKVM guest with Ubuntu 14.04.01

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ldap, ppc64le

I was able to create a Ubuntu guest under PowerKVM and installed 14.04.1 on it.

I set up ssh, telnet and set things up so I could log into the root account

Then I installed the LDAP client and tried to log in to one of the ldap accounts but get failures that look to be from a library reference in authentication (pam?/python?)

**All of the following detail (bad things) happen when I set authentication to LDAP** in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf file`.

If I remain using local accounts, logins, etc things work just fine.

1 - Most importantly, if I reboot, the system hangs with the following message in the console

```
 /usr/bin/python3: symbol lookup error: /lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libnss_ldap.so.2: undefined symbol: __libc_lock_lock
```

2 - If I su to the account -

```
su - metheuser
Segmentation fault
```

3 - If I SSH or telnet to the server, the following message shows up in the syslog file

```
kernel: [  146.489209] su[1000]: unhandled signal 11 at 00003fffb6434000 nip 00003fffb64062d4 lr 00003fffb6406298 code 30001
```

My problem is that I need to set it up for LDAP authentication and automount through LDAP but am having issues.  Where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a regression bug in PowerKVM.

An update to PowerKVM is expected in the coming weeks - we can be contacted on DeveloperWorks if a fix is desired sooner.  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/group/tpl

There is no work-around known...  LDAP is not typically a common-case..